# Numba dictionary operations taking 30X more time than pure python dictionary operations

Tags: python-3.x, numba

Following are the implementations of jitted and non jitted functions. The jitted function takes around 30X more time than that of non jitted function. I was expecting numba to improve the performance.

```
Sample Input:
    common_keys = List()
    dict_B[("4tglt", "101", "9")] = 90
    dict_B[("4tglt", "102", "102")] = 30
    common_keys.append(("4tglt", "101", "9"))
    dict_A[("4tglt", "101", "9")] = np.asanyarray([15013958])
```

With this simple input:
Jitted function executes in 61.9 µs ± 87.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Non Jitted function executes in 838 ns ± 89.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each).

30X increase in timing for the Jitted function happens when the dict_A and dict_B size increases. dict_A and dict_B can have around 100K entries.

```
    Jitted Function:
    -----------------
    
    from numba.typed import List, Dict

    dict_A = Dict.empty(
             key_type=types.Tuple((types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type)),
             value_type=types.int64[:],
         )
    dict_B = Dict.empty(
         key_type=types.Tuple((types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type)),
         value_type=types.int64,
    )
    common_keys = List()  # This is list of tuples of type (types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type, types.unicode_type)
    
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def final_calculations(common_keys, dict_A, dict_B):
        final_out_dict = Dict.empty(
            key_type=types.int64,
            value_type=types.int64,
        )
        for key in common_keys:
            for v in dict_A.get(key):
                if key in dict_B:
                    if v not in final_out_dict:
                        final_out_dict[v] = 0
                    final_out_dict[v] += dict_B[key]
        return final_out_dict


       Non Jitted function:
        --------------------
        
        def final_calculations(common_keys, dict_A, dict_B):
            final_out_dict = defaultdict(int)
            for key in common_keys:
                for v in dict_A.get(key):
                    final_out_dict[v] += dict_B[key]
            return final_out_dict
```

Comment: How large are your inputs, and what actual measured amount of time does each take?  Also, note your non-JIT version seems to have mismatched variable names, you may want to clean that up to clarify your question.

Comment: What is in, and how large is `final_ranked_tcins`

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have cleanup the code.

Comment: @ReblochonMasqueThe final_out_dict can have any size. It is not fixed.

Comment: Does `timeit` give a similar time if you run it again right away on the JIT version?  That is, with the JIT code already compiled and warm?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes it give similar performance even if i run it again for the JIT version.